# parse youtube video likes dislikes using gadata API

Tags: python, youtube-api, social-media-like

I am using python and the gdata library to parse the info of a youtube video.
My code is this:

```
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='someid')
```

but in the `entry.rating` or `entry.statistics` there is no likes/dislikes

Where can I get that info from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I use Python 3 and the gdata library doesn't have support for it I couldn't reproduce the results. 
But as far as I know, the `entry.rating` returns a xml code with the whole statistic content of the video.
For a more specific result you should try `entry.rating.average` or `entry.rating.num_raters`

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the source](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/youtube/data.py#407) of the `gdata` library, it doesn't seem that it supports YouTube's like/dislike Gdata `<yt:rating>` element, only the generic `<gd:rating>` element.

If you are able to somehow access the underlying XML element through the library (I haven't used it myself), you should be able to get your hands at the YouTube rating element (qualified name should be `{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007}rating`, if that helps :) ).

Even better, if you are able to patch the library to actually natively support that element, all the better. I'm sure the authors would appreciate a patch. :)